# Most efficient way to store nested categories (or hierarchical data) in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

We have nested categories for several products (e.g., **Sports -> Basketball -> Men's**, **Sports -> Tennis -> Women's** ) and are using Mongo instead of MySQL.

We know how to store nested categories in a SQL database like MySQL, but would appreciate any advice on what to do for Mongo. The operation we need to optimize for is quickly finding all products in one category or subcategory, which could be nested several layers below a root category (e.g., all products in the **Men's Basketball** category or all products in the **Women's Tennis** category).

[This Mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) suggests one approach, but it says it doesn't work well when operations are needed for subtrees, which we need (since categories can reach multiple levels).

Any suggestions on the best way to efficiently store and search nested categories of arbitrary depth?

Comment: materialised paths are strong at querying while slower at updating

Comment: the mongodb docs link lists five approaches, not one and I think the third one seems perfectly adequate for your use case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first thing you want to decide is exactly what kind of tree you will use.

The big thing to consider is your data and access patterns. You have already stated that 90% of all your work will be querying and by the sounds of it (e-commerce) updates will only be run by administrators, most likely rarely.

So you want a schema that gives you the power of querying quickly on child through a path, i.e.: Sports -> Basketball -> Men's, Sports -> Tennis -> Women's, and doesn't really need to truly scale to updates.

As you so rightly pointed out MongoDB does have a good documentation page for this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/ whereby 10gen actually state different models and schema methods for trees and describes the main ups and downs of them.

The one that should catch the eye if you are looking to query easily is materialised paths: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/

This is a very interesting method to build up trees since to query on the example you gave above into "Womens" in "Tennis" you could simply do a pre-fixed regex (which can use the index: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/ ) like so:

```
db.products.find({category: /^Sports,Tennis,Womens[,]/})
```

to find all products listed under a certain path of your tree.

Unfortunately this model is really bad at updating, if you move a category or change its name you have to update all products and there could be thousands of products under one category.

A better method would be to house a `cat_id` on the product and then separate the categories into a separate collection with the schema:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(),
    name: 'Women\'s',
    path: 'Sports,Tennis,Womens',
    normed_name: 'all_special_chars_and_spaces_and_case_senstive_letters_taken_out_like_this'
}
```

So now your queries only involve the categories collection which should make them much smaller and more performant. The exception to this is when you delete a category, the products will still need touching.

So an example of changing "Tennis" to "Badmin":

```
db.categories.update({path:/^Sports,Tennis[,]/}).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.path = doc.path.replace(/,Tennis/, ",Badmin");
    db.categories.save(doc);
});
```

Unfortunately MongoDB provides no in-query document reflection at the moment so you do have to pull them out client side which is a little annoying, however hopefully it shouldn't result in too many categories being brought back.

And this is basically how it works really. It is a bit of a pain to update but the power of being able to query instantly on any path using an index is more fitting for your scenario I believe.

Of course the added benefit is that this schema is compatible with nested set models: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model which I have found time and time again are just awesome for e-commerce sites, for example, Tennis might be under both "Sports" and "Leisure" and you want multiple paths depending on where the user came from.

The schema for materialised paths easily supports this by just adding another `path`, that simple.

Hope it makes sense, quite a long one there.

Comment: Thanks! What if we want need to store category meta information (e.g., name and id)? Should we set aside a separate collection for categories then use the ID in the category path for the products? We don't expect the category information to change very often, maybe once a year.

Comment: @Crashalot Yea if something is assigned to the category it is normally best to store it on the category, the alternative is to store it on every product and even though it wont change often it seems logical that when you get the category you will want to get its meta data as well aside from the products

Comment: Cool, thanks for the confirmation. This also suggests we store the category ID in the path instead of the category name. Is there anything you see that's wrong with this? Also do you have experience storing and querying hierarchical data in Mongo? Just curious if you're interested in a tiny consulting project. :)

Comment: @Crashalot The only thing is that to understand a path to query on you will need to pull out the _id for the category from somewhere, whether it be each category in the path or from the product, however if you make a breadcrumb it is highly likely you will pull out those categories anyway so nah I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Crashalot I do have quite a bit of experience, I made a Google help system for my MongoDB video site in it, it works quite well, also done a few other projects that require trees in MongoDB

Comment: @Crashalot ignore that last comment you can get the entire breadcrumb by sorting on path

Comment: when you say, add another path, how exactly does that work? you put all the paths into an array? the info i'm looking for in particular is your hourly rate.

Comment: @Crashalot You could put all paths into an array and use elemMatch or if you wanna define differences in names by storing them in separate fields you can

Comment: if we put multiple paths into an array, how can we use regex to perform fast queries? don't we lose the speed aspects of the materialized path approach? thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Crashalot Actually I don't think you will need elemMatch for this since it would just be a string per path so: `db.categories.find({path:/^path,to,somewhere/})` will do since MongoDB is of course transparent when it comes to querying arrays

Comment: thanks, didn't realize it was transparent for querying arrays! do you recommend any of the cloud mongo providers like mongohq or mongolabs?

Comment: @Crashalot This is where I am a bit daft, I have never used a provider; I always make and host my own MongoDB on AWS however I have heard good stuff about both of those so it is probably really subjective, or price based, as to which you go for

Comment: thanks, and i take it you're not interested in any consulting jobs (since you keep sidestepping the question :))?

Comment: @Crashalot If you have questions like this one that are not too consuming I will allow emails to my public email address which I forwarded, I answer quite a few people. If you require my full attention and many hours work then I will say something :)

Comment: @Crashalot so moving categories to diff collection won't that make it 2 queries now when we search (as compare to earlier) and hence bad? Or will it be same / marginally bad since categories collection would be small?

Comment: @Sammaye i don't understand your point about nested sets models and multiple paths. isn't one of the assumptions of nested sets that there is a unique path for each node? or are you saying that you would have multiple nested set models, and store an array of paths at each node?

Comment: There are a few ways of allowing nested sets to do multiple paths. One way  do is to actually add duplicate fields for the left, right and level so you can fill in left1 or right1 etc etc

Comment: But now that I relook over it, it is better to just cataloge an item in two duplicate categories in two locations

Answer (score 4):

If all categories are distinct then think of them as tags. The hierarchy isn't necessary to encode in the items because you don't need them when you query for items. The hierarchy is a presentational thing. Tag each item with all the categories in it's path, so "Sport > Baseball > Shoes" could be saved as `{..., categories: ["sport", "baseball", "shoes"], ...}`. If you want all items in the "Sport" category, search for `{categories: "sport"}`, if you want just the shoes, search for `{tags: "shoes"}`.

This doesn't capture the hierarchy, but if you think about it that doesn't matter. If the categories are distinct, the hierarchy doesn't help you when you query for items. There will be no other "baseball", so when you search for that you will only get things below the "baseball" level in the hierarchy.

My suggestion relies on categories being distinct, and I guess they aren't in your current model. However, there's no reason why you can't make them distinct. You've probably chosen to use the strings you display on the page as category names in the database. If you instead use symbolic names like "sport" or "womens_shoes" and use a lookup table to find the string to display on the page (this will also save you hours of work if the name of a category ever changes -- and it will make translating the site easier, if you would ever need to do that) you can easily make sure that they are distinct because they don't have anything to do with what is displayed on the page. So if you have two "Shoes" in the hierarchy (for example "Tennis > Women's > Shoes" and "Tennis > Men's > Shoes") you can just add a qualifier to make them distinct (for example "womens_shoes" and "mens_shoes", or "tennis_womens_shoes") The symbolic names are arbitrary and can be anything, you could even use numbers and just use the next number in the sequence every time you add a category.

Comment: The last part of your answer using the qualifiers like that is a lot like materialised paths except it has no true standardisation to its perceived depth and formation, which some might see as bad in that respect.

Comment: It's definitely not materialized paths, I do not suggest that the symbolic names should include the full hierarchy, they can be completely arbitrary. My examples only include parts of the hierarchy because the labels were so very generic. They should be as specific as possible, but no more. I believe that encoding the hierarchy into the items in the database is an anti-pattern. The hierarchy is a presentational detail, and using materialized paths needlessly repeats the hierarchy for every item, making the data model brittle, and making it unnecessarily hard to change the hierarchy later.